# How do I wait to sentences finish before Android executes setContentView(..)?

Tags: android, setcontentview

As I have seen, Android doesn't wait to execute all sentences before a sentence like setContentView(...).

For example, I can't do this:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int seg = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int sum = 1;
    for (int i = seg; i < 5 + seg; i++){
        for(int j = min; j < 10000+ min; j++){
            seg = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            sum += seg;
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(sum), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    setContentView(R.layout.results);
```

Android executes setContentView before the calculations finish. How I can do that Android wait sentences before?

Comment: what exactly is your requirement?

Comment: Sorry, you're just wrong here.  Java executes every line in a function sequentially.  It is not possible for it to skip lines or go to the next one before the previous one finishes.  You might have a bug somewhere in your code, but its not that.  If its that you aren't seeing 5 toasts before it sets the content view-  that's because showing a toast sends a message to another thread.  There is no way to stop untll all the toasts have been shown, if you need that functionality you need to roll your own toast-like UI.

Comment: In general, `Toast` is the wrong solution for nearly every UI problem. People like me use it in books for simplicity, not because it's a great idea to use a `Toast`.